# Xamarin nuget package update failed for android app

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget

Update nuget package for my project failed. please check the check the screenshot if you can give me a solution

[image]

Comment: Are you using old packags.config or the newer PackageReferences? Either way try manually deleting everything in the "packages" folder, delete all obj/bin folders, and then reopen the solution and try to build.

Comment: @Mahmud,According to your description, what is SampleDependency package? I find one thread that you can take a look:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2645

Comment: SampleDependency does not exist on nuget.org. I would guess there is a missing package source. Where is SampleDependency from?